# React JSX editing style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just spent hours trying to understand what broke my sample app before I found this:

Working example:

```
let cards = this.props.cards.map(
  (card) => {
    return <Card id = {card.id}
                 title = {card.title}
                 description = {card.description}
                 color = {card.color}
                 tasks = {card.tasks} />
  });
```

Broken example:

```
let cards = this.props.cards.map(
  (card) => {
    return 
    <Card id = {card.id}
          title = {card.title}
          description = {card.description}
          color = {card.color}
          tasks = {card.tasks} />
  });
```

Should the JSX syntax be this sensitive or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your broken example result will be

```
[undefined, ...., undefined]
```

because JS interpreter understands it like this(note `;` after `return`),

```
let cards = this.props.cards.map(
  (card) => {
    return;

    <Card id = {card.id}
          title = {card.title}
          description = {card.description}
          color = {card.color}
          tasks = {card.tasks} />
  });
```

if you add new line after `return` - JS interpreter inserts semicolon automatically, and this is not problem with JSX